# Merge 2 XML files

Tags: xml, merge

I've tried a lot off different things, to merge 2 XML files, XSTL 1.0 for instance. But I am still not 100% able. It needs to work on Linux and Windows and by now I don't care how it works, it just needs to work. So if it uses a tool, jar, xstl 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 or whatever. As long as it works simple and it is easy to change, it is fine by me. It should be as generic as possible.

Basicly the input XML contains a complete XML structure.
If the names match (and the attributes have the same value) the value should be taken from the 2nd file. If the 2nd XML contains a new element, it should be added.

Futhermore there are NVPairs (Name Value Pairs) on different locations in the XML file. If the names match, the value of the value field should be taken from the 2nd file. If the 2nd file contains a new name value pair, it should be added to the result.

I've worked out a simplified example.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/Test" name="TEST">
    <repoInstanceName>testRepo</repoInstanceName>
    <NVPairs name="Global Variables">
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>Host</name>
            <value>localhost</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePairInteger>
            <name>Timeout</name>
            <value>60</value>
        </NameValuePairInteger>
    </NVPairs>
    <repoInstances selected="local">
        <localRepoInstance>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </localRepoInstance>
    </repoInstances>
    <services>
        <bw name="1.par">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="1">
                    <machine>localhost</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>testtype</type>
                        <version>12.9</version>
                    </product>
                    <contact>mailme</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <threadCount>12</threadCount>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>128</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>512</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
            <NVPairs name="Adapter SDK Properties">
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>Trace.Task.*</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>EnableMemorySavingMode</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
            </NVPairs>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
            <failureInterval>0</failureInterval>
            <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="process1">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>true</activation>
                    <flowLimit>8</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>
            </bwprocesses>
            <checkpoints selected="Local File">
                <checkpoint>Local File</checkpoint>
                <checkpoint>/lalaa/</checkpoint>
                <tablePrefix>ffffl_7787</tablePrefix>
            </checkpoints>
            <isFt>false</isFt>
        </bw>
        <bw name="2.par">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="2">
                    <machine>other</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>testtype2</type>
                        <version>12.9</version>
                    </product>
                    <contact>mailme</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <threadCount>12</threadCount>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>128</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>512</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
            <NVPairs name="Adapter SDK Properties">
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>Trace.Task.*</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>EnableMemorySavingMode</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
            </NVPairs>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
            <failureInterval>0</failureInterval>
            <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="process1">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>true</activation>
                    <flowLimit>8</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="process2">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>true</activation>
                    <flowLimit>8</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>                
            </bwprocesses>
            <checkpoints selected="Local File">
                <checkpoint>Local File</checkpoint>
                <checkpoint>/lalaa/</checkpoint>
                <tablePrefix>ffffl_7787</tablePrefix>
            </checkpoints>
            <isFt>false</isFt>
        </bw>       
    </services>
</application>
```

replaceOrAdd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/Test" name="TEST">
    <NVPairs name="Global Variables">
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>Host</name>
            <value>newhost</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePairPassword>
            <name>PasswordDB</name>
            <value>secret</value>
        </NameValuePairPassword>        
    </NVPairs>
    <repoInstances selected="local">
        <localRepoInstance>
            <encoding>UTF-16</encoding>
            <newParameter>ADD_ME</newParameter>
        </localRepoInstance>
    </repoInstances>
    <services>
        <bw name="1.par">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="1">
                    <machine>testRepo</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>testtype122</type>
                    </product>
                    <setting>
                        <threadCount>7</threadCount>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>32</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <timeout>7</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
            <NVPairs name="Adapter SDK Properties">
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>EnableMemorySavingMode</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </NameValuePair>
            </NVPairs>
            <checkpoints selected="Local File">
                <checkpoint>Other File</checkpoint>
            </checkpoints>
        </bw>
        <bw name="2.par">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="process1">
                    <activation>false</activation>
                    <flowLimit>16</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="process2">
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </bwprocess>                
            </bwprocesses>
            <isFt>true</isFt>
        </bw>       
    </services>
</application>
```

Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/Test" name="TEST">
    <repoInstanceName>testRepo</repoInstanceName>
    <NVPairs name="Global Variables">
        <NameValuePair>
            <name>Host</name>
            <value>newhost</value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePairInteger>
            <name>Timeout</name>
            <value>60</value>
        </NameValuePairInteger>
        <NameValuePairPassword>
            <name>PasswordDB</name>
            <value>secret</value>
        </NameValuePairPassword>        
    </NVPairs>
    <repoInstances selected="local">
        <localRepoInstance>
            <encoding>UTF-16</encoding>
            <newParameter>ADD_ME</newParameter>
        </localRepoInstance>
    </repoInstances>
    <services>
        <bw name="1.par">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="1">
                    <machine>testRepo</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>testtype122</type>
                        <version>12.9</version>
                    </product>
                    <contact>mailme</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <threadCount>7</threadCount>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>32</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>512</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>7</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
            <NVPairs name="Adapter SDK Properties">
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>Trace.Task.*</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>EnableMemorySavingMode</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </NameValuePair>
            </NVPairs>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
            <failureInterval>0</failureInterval>
            <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="process1">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>true</activation>
                    <flowLimit>8</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>
            </bwprocesses>
            <checkpoints selected="Local File">
                <checkpoint>Other File</checkpoint>
                <checkpoint>/lalaa/</checkpoint>
                <tablePrefix>ffffl_7787</tablePrefix>
            </checkpoints>
            <isFt>false</isFt>
        </bw>
        <bw name="2.par">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="2">
                    <machine>other</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>testtype2</type>
                        <version>12.9</version>
                    </product>
                    <contact>mailme</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <threadCount>12</threadCount>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>128</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>512</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
            <NVPairs name="Adapter SDK Properties">
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>Trace.Task.*</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
                <NameValuePair>
                    <name>EnableMemorySavingMode</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </NameValuePair>
            </NVPairs>
            <failureCount>0</failureCount>
            <failureInterval>0</failureInterval>
            <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="process1">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>false</activation>
                    <flowLimit>16</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="process2">
                    <starter>name</starter>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <maxJob>8</maxJob>
                    <activation>true</activation>
                    <flowLimit>8</flowLimit>
                </bwprocess>                
            </bwprocesses>
            <checkpoints selected="Local File">
                <checkpoint>Local File</checkpoint>
                <checkpoint>/lalaa/</checkpoint>
                <tablePrefix>ffffl_7787</tablePrefix>
            </checkpoints>
            <isFt>true</isFt>
        </bw>       
    </services>
</application>
```

Comment: It could be done in VS (c# or VB.net) and create a exe executable.  The exe can be run on Linux PC.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was hoping for a bit more direction. A tool that can do this or a bit of xslt code or maybe a link to something useful.

Comment: I could write the code but I as waiting to see if you wanted to take this approach.  Is it always the same section of xml that needs merge or entire document?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. This can be handled in XSLT run by practically all general purpose languages (Java, C#, Python, PHP, VB) but what you attempted that we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: I've been developing the XSTL 1.0 code the past 6 months. It works nice, but it is not flexible, if one field needs to be added, I'm busy for an other day.  I've found generic java code (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077736/open-source-tools/xml-merging-made-easy.html) for merging 2 XML files, got the jar from here (https://jikax001-gstreamer.googlecode.com/git-history/5c3baa1393d3401af282fe9e2ce402fe6f07fa4d/Shared/Java/xmlmerge.jar) and it works nice out of the box, but the problem there is that when 2 elements match, the values are merged from the input and merge XML.

Comment: Lastly i've found the generic xslt code on this site, http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/ (merge.xslt), this also works ok with my xalan 2.7.2 parser but this goes wrong when the attribute fields are not in the same order within the input and merge XML. So maybe there an other flexivble generic solution, that doesn't take too much coding